# How to pass default values to controller by routing in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, routes

In laravel, if I want to pass parameters to a controller in my route file

```
Route::get('user/sk/{id}'  , 'UsersController@findsk');
```

If I want to pass default parameters:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {

     // how do I invoke my controller here?

     return $name;

});
```

How do I merge the two things? Is there a shortcut?

```
Route::get('user/sk/{id}'  , 'UsersController@findsk'

   // can I add an array of default parameters here?

);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no shortcut, unfortunately.

**To inject one optional parameter:**

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
    $ctrl = new \App\Http\Controllers\UsersController();
    return $ctrl->findsk($name);
});
```

**To inject one optional parameter with more parameters:**
Assuming you had an `$id` param and that `UsersController@findsk` accepts `$id` and `$name`.

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{name?}', function ($id, $name = 'John') {
    $ctrl = new \App\Http\Controllers\UsersController();
    return $ctrl->findsk($id, $name);
});
```

**To inject something in the controller from the router:**
Assuming want to use a url as a switch.

```
Route::get('my-special-url', function () {
    $ctrl = new \App\Http\Controllers\UsersController();
    return $ctrl->findsk(1, 'Paul');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass as a default parameter to function in your controller like just normal function

```
Route::get('user/sk/{id}'  , 'UsersController@findsk');
```

in `UsersController`

```
function findsk($id ='myVal'){

}
```

Comment: Ok but what if I want to manage more than one var/default value with one controller?  Route::get('user/sk/{id}'  , 'UsersController@find'); and Route::get('user/email/{id}'  , 'UsersController@find');   If email I would like it to be: function find($what='email', $id ='myVal');  if sk: function find($what='sk', $id ='myVal')