# How can i get all date even dates that don't have a record by eloquent with group by?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a method that get a month parameter to select rows of that month from users table. I want to show count of registered user for a month.

```
public function registeredUsersDaily($month)
{
     $countOfDailyRegisteredUsersForAMonth = User::user()
        ->where(DB::raw('created_at'), '=', $month)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date')
        ->get([
            DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')
        ]);
    dd($countOfDailyRegisteredUsersForAMonth);
}
```

It return count only for dates that exists in users table, so i want to have zero for dates that don't exists.

```
|date|count|  
| 5  | 10  |  
| 15 | 3   |
```

I want to have a result like this:

```
|date   |count  |
| 1     | 0     |
| 2     | 0     |
| 3     | 0     |
| 4     | 0     |
| 5     | 10    |
| 6     | 0     |
| 7     | 0     |
| 8     | 0     |
| 9     | 0     |
| 10    | 0     |
| 11    | 0     |
| 12    | 0     |
| 13    | 0     |
| 14    | 0     |
| 15    | 3     |
```

....

Comment: What do you mean by "dates that don't exist", or what is stored in this dates

Comment: Dates that no one registered, in my example in 5/11/2018 , 10 users registered, and in 15/11/2018, 3 users registered, but in other dates no one registered.

Comment: @Ahadabasirad Please check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

Please check out like this

```
$dateValues = array_column($countOfDailyRegisteredUsersForAMonth, "date");
$maxDate    = max($dateValues);
$likeYouWant=[];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxDate; $i++)
{
    $likeYouWant[] = ["date" => $i, "count" => in_array($i, $dateValues) ? $countOfDailyRegisteredUsersForAMonth[array_search($i, $dateValues)]["count"] : 0];
}
print_r($likeYouWant);
```

Comment: Please check latest simplified version

Answer (score 0):

If you want default date than you can mention in that `migration` file or you can also do that in your `model` from where you can retrieve data when there is no date given by user.
You can also refer this for more

[How to pass default values to controller by routing in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871910/how-to-pass-default-values-to-controller-by-routing-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've got from the comments: 
I think the best thing here is to count the number of users created each day of the month. This will get you zero's in case no one registered on a given date.
With this, you'd probably loop through the dates checking the total users registered each date.

For instance, let's try to get the users created the last 30 days from now:

```
$results = [];

$startOfDay = now()->createMidnightDate();

for($i=0; $i<=30; $i++)
{
    $total_count = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$startOfDay->subDays($i-1), $startOfDay->subDays($i)])
        ->count();

    array_push($results[ $startOfDay->subDays($i)->format('d')], $total_count);
}
```

With this I think you can now work with the results from the array.